# JSONEncoder subclass to return actual JSON representation, not serializable object

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to encode instances of a custom python class `ISOWeek` using python 2.7's builtin `json` module. I want it to be encoded not to a JS string (such as `"2012-08"`), but to a constructor call: `new ISOWeek({year: 2012, kw: 8})`. Python's `json` docs say I should sublass `JSONEncoder` and override the `default` method, however I can only return another JSON serializable object from it, not the actual serialization. Looking at the `json.py` source, I don't see an obvious way to hack the module. Any suggestions?

Comment: What does your original input look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of putting a constructor call directly into the JSON (which makes it invalid JSON), I would recommend formatting your data so that you know what is going on, and just modify the JS to do the correct conversion, for example instead of the following:

```
{"date": new ISOWeek({year: 2012, kw: 8})}
```

I would suggest something like this:

```
{"date": ["ISOWeek", {"year": 2012, "kw": 8}]}
```

Comment: Right, I didn't realize I was violating the JSON specs. I found that the `demjson` package from pypi has an encoder class which can produce what I wanted, but it's probably better to solve this correctly. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's valid JSON.  See http://www.json.org/.  You can do that in JavaScript, but in JSON you are limited to the basic types (strings, numbers, booleans, null, and lists/dicts of those types).

You could serialize it to a string version of your constructor, or some other object containing the relevant info.  But one way or another you'll need to do the processing on the *receiving* end to decode it to your ISOWeek object.

Comment: Yes, that's the answer.  Python's JSON encoder is for producing JSON.